# Image Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am looking for a drop down list which can present the user with a series of images to choose from. Each image will be about 50x50 pixels and a small text description will be under the image. A jQuery and compatable ASP.NET solution would be preferred.

Comment: I have come across this control [customSelect][1] but I feel like it could be better. It looks like there will also need to be additional work to get it to post the selection to the server.


  [1]: http://finalevillee.googlepages.com/jqueryplugin%3Acustomselect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a super basic jQuery plug in to accomplish this. What will happen is a a fake drop down list will be created from an existing select tag. The original select will be hidden, and the fake menu will be shown. As the new menu is being created, it will callback to get the HTML to show for each option. In this function you can pass back an image.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.templatedSelect = function(options) {

var defaults = {
    selectHandleImage : "selectHandle.gif",
    width : "65px",
    getOption : function(value, text) {
            return text;
        }
};
var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var $originalSelect = this;

    var $container = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .css("clear", "both")
        .css("width", opts.width)
        .hover(
            function () {
                $selectBox.css("border-color", "#000000");
            }, 
            function () {
                if (!$menuItems.is(":visible"))
                    $selectBox.css("border-color", "#C0C0C0");
            })
        .attr('id', "imageSelect_container_" + this.attr('id'));

    var $selectBox = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .css("border", "solid 1px #C0C0C0")
        .css("overflow", "hidden")
        .css("width", "100%")

    var $selectedItem = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .css("padding", "4px");

    var $selectHandle = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .css("float", "right")
        .css("background-color", "#F0F0F0")
        .css("padding", "4px") 
        .css("cursor", "hand")          
        .click(function(e) {
            ToggleMenuItems();
        })
        .html(
            $(document.createElement('img')).attr("src", opts.selectHandleImage)
        );

    var $menuItems = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("margin-top", "-1px")
        .css("border", "solid 1px #000000")
        .css("background-color", "#FFFFFF")
        .hide();

    $originalSelect.children("option").each(function(i, selected) {   
        var $menuItem = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .css("padding", "4px")
            .html(opts.getOption($(this).val(), $(this).text()))
            .val($(this).val())
            .click(function(e) {
                ToggleMenuItems();
                $originalSelect.val($(this).val());
                $selectedItem.html($(this).html());
            })
            .hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#81BEF7");
                }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
                })
            .appendTo($menuItems);
    });

    //preset the selectedItem
    $selectedItem.html(
        $menuItems.children("div:eq("+$originalSelect[0].selectedIndex+")").html()
    );

    //put everything together
    $selectBox.appendTo($container);
    $selectHandle.appendTo($selectBox);
    $selectedItem.appendTo($selectBox);
    $menuItems.appendTo($container);

    //hide the original select and put ours in
    $originalSelect.hide();
    $container.insertBefore($originalSelect);

    $selectHandle.height($selectBox.height());
    $menuItems.width($selectBox.width());

    function ToggleMenuItems() {
        if ($menuItems.is(":visible")) {
            $menuItems.hide();
            $selectBox.css("border", "solid 1px #C0C0C0");
        } else {
            $menuItems.show();
            $selectBox.css("border", "solid 1px #000000");
        }
    }

}})(jQuery);
```

To use, call templatedSelect on your existing select. Also pass in a function to resolve the template for each item

```
    $().ready(function() {
        $('#selectId').templatedSelect({
            getOption : function(v, t) {
                return "<img src='" + v + "'/><br/>" + t; 
            }
        });
```

Comment: u can pass multiple styles into .css e.g .css( {color:'red', left:'10px'} )