# add image in option

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me how can i add an image in Select box

HTML

```
<option  id ="OP_{$LANG.MY_ID}" class="boardDialog" style="font-size:12px" value="OP_{$LANG.MY_ID}">
```

CSS

```
.boardDialog{

    background-image: url(../images/Work_Board_Member.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

This is working fine on Mozilla but does not work in IE and Google chrome.
Can anyone tell me how can i do this google chrome

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to achieve this functionality using the select tag. You have to make a custom control for this.

Here is an example

[Combobox with icons:](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml)

Also found a similar SO question

[Image Dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290493/image-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 2):

this isnt possible in IE and probably chrome. The only real workaround is to create a faux dropdown using javascript but this isnt really advisable - unless it degrades gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

+1 with seengee, except for the not only advisable. You can implement this kind of "control" in your website, it depends how you do.

You create a dropdown using javascript, but the page have to work good, using a normal dropdown, if someone come up with disabled javascript, or a mobile device.

You can see kind of this drop down on facebook, or "web 2.0 javascript ajax full of crap" websites.

Comment: yes, I should have pointed out that its not advisable unless it degrades gracefully